# Multiple select amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have different selects with different values in them. How can I get total amount of those values?

For example I have

```
<select class="total">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
<select class="total">
    <option>2</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

And if I select from the first select `1` and from the second `2` I want to get `3` as result.

http://jsfiddle.net/vQ8Bm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look through the selected elements and convert each to an integer, then add them.

```
var sum = 0;
$('.total :selected').each(function () {
    sum += parseInt($(this).text());
});
```

- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YnMJ4/2/)

**UPDATE**

Inside the select change event

```
$('.total').change(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.total :selected').each(function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I add this to a function? `function() { yourcode }` and reuse it?

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.total').on('change', function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $('.total').each(function () {
            sum += parseInt(this.value, 10);
        });
        alert(sum);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ8Bm/2/)

Comment: this doesn't get the selected options

Comment: @NickKnudson it does as `select.value` is thing as `$('select option:selected').val();`

Answer (score 4):

Just in case, a vanilla-js solution

```
var map = Array.prototype.map;

var res = map.call(document.getElementsByClassName('total'), function( select ) {
    return select.value;
}).reduce(function( a, b ) {
    return +a + +b;
});

alert(res);
```

*demo:* http://jsfiddle.net/vQ8Bm/6/

Comment: Always nice to have a plain JS answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Get the sum of the values across multiple `<select>`s:

```
var total = 0;
$('select.total').each(function () {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".total").change(function() {
    var sum = $(".total").map(function() {
        return +this.value;
    }).get().reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
    console.log(sum);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vQ8Bm/4/

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski It is not that hard if you look precisely :)

Comment: anyway +1 for nice example of `reduce`, `get`, `map` usage and tricky parseint :))